# For what reason stack property is optional in Error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

In an `Error`, the property `stack` is optional. However, when I throw a `new Error('myError')` or when I have a generic error thrown during the execution of my script, I always get the stack. According to the browser, the stack is not the same but I is not `undefined`.

- I was wondering in which case it was possible to have an undefined stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stack` property is not defined by the [JavaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-error-objects) (yet). So a compliant JavaScript implementation could well not have a `stack` property on `Error` instances. Most do nowadays (certainly the big three: V8, SpiderMonkey, and JavaSciptCore), but it's not standardized (yet), so they don't *have* to.

> In an `Error`, the property `stack` is optional.

I'm guessing you're referring to TypeScript's type information for `Error`:

```typescript
interface Error {
    stack?: string | undefined;
}
```

Since most JavaScript engines *do* provide a `stack` property of type `string` even though it's not defined by the specification, making it optional with the type `string | undefined` is a pragmatic choice (the TypeScript project team are notoriously pragmatic). So rather than leave it out entirely, they acknowledge the common practice.

> I was wondering in which case it was possible to have an `undefined` stack?

I think it's unlikely you'd have an `undefined` `stack` on an `Error` instance on implementations that support it (more likely `""` if no stack information is available, but I don't recall seeing a blank `stack`). That said, there's likely a reason TYpeScript's types define it as `stack?: string | undefined` and not `stack?: string`.

Comment: Alright, but it means that if I use common browser like `Chrome`, `Firefox` or `Edge`, I will have the stack property anyway?

Comment: @PierBJX - Chrome and Edge use V8 and Firefox uses SpiderMonkey (in both cases: except on iOS, where Apple won't let them). Both of those JavaScript engines support `stack`. So does JavaScriptCore on Mac OS and iOS. I'm not aware of any case where it wouldn't be present and be a string.

Comment: I am on MacOS, and so far I have the `stack` for these 3 browsers. I did not try the other since my application just have to support those. @T.J Crowder

Comment: @PierBJX - You're all set then. :-) If you want to make TypeScript happy (I'm guessing you're using TypeScript), you could do `e.stack ?? ""` or `e.stack ?? String(e)` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to do `e.stack ?? e.toString()` which is quite the same